# Problems with @differentiable in Swift for TensorFlow

Tags: swift, tensorflow

I'm completely new to swift for TF, but find it interesting and wanted to try it out. I downloaded it and tried to used it in Xcode but always get a "Abort trap 6" error while building.

Here's my Code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // let y = 1.3
        // var grad = gradient(at: 2.0) {x in self.testfunction(x,y)}
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    @differentiable
    func testfunction(_ x: Double, _ y: Double) -> Double {
        return (x*y) + (x/y) * x
        }



}
```

The Code works, if I comment out the @differentiable. I choose the swift for TF Toolchain.

Anybody has an Idea? I tried some idea's I read of (e.g. Disabled Compiler Optimization), but nothing worked. I'm grateful for every idea!

Comment: Just to understand the question better, which sample are you trying to run using tensor flow.

Comment: What do you mean with sample? I only try to use the @differentiable, I have not come to TensorFlow yet unfortunatly.